# How to analyze a java thread dump correctly?

Tags: java, thread-dump

I am trying to understand more about java thread dump.
I am using JBOSS EAP 4.3.

Currently i am facing performance issue in one of my environment.
suddenly the CPU utilization went up to 700%.  I took the thread dump and it is huge file.

I found lot of below waiting thread entries in my threaddump.

```
"http-172.16.101.99-8080-4" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000059d16800 nid=0x5803 in Object.wait() [0x00002b00cf683000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000070c1eef60> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await(JIoEndpoint.java:416)
    - locked <0x000000070c1eef60> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:442)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I want to understand from above waiting thread. what caused the CPU utilization went up ?

Comment: waiting threads do not utilize CPU

Comment: look for RUNNING or RUNNABLE threads instead

Comment: How to know which object is waiting for.   is there any way to find out exact root cause of the issue ?

Comment: you can see it is `waiting on <0x000000070c1eef60>`. Search for that number to see who has a lock on it.

Answer (score 0):

There are 6 different thread states:

1. NEW
2. WAITING
3. TIMED_WAITING
4. RUNNABLE
5. BLOCKED
6. TERMINATED

NEW, WAITING, TIMED_WAITING, BLOCKED, TERMINATED state threads **do not** consume CPU. Only the threads in RUNNABLE state consume CPU. So, if your application's CPU is spiking up, you should focus only on the RUNNABLE state threads stack trace.

Capturing thread dumps, along with **‘top -H -p ’** output will help you to identify the threads that are causing CPU to spike. Here is a [good article](https://blog.fastthread.io/2018/12/13/how-to-troubleshoot-cpu-problems/) which walks you through how to troubleshoot CPU spikes.